# CGAffineTransform blocking frame movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, user-interface, transform

I just realized something quite strange. Using the storyboard in Xcode 5, I create a very simple app; a view controller with only one view. On this view there is slider and two images. When i move the slider i want one image to scale and the other to move. I connect the controls to the view controller

TestViewController.h:

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *scaleImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *moveImage;

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender;

@end
```

And implement the sliderChanged in TestViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    self.scaleImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale([sender value], [sender value]);

    CGRect targetFrame = self.moveImage.frame;
    targetFrame.origin = CGPointMake(targetFrame.origin.x + (100 * [sender value]) - 50, targetFrame.origin.y);
    self.moveImage.frame = targetFrame;
}
```

Now comes the strange part. When I drag the slider the scale image is correctly scaled, but the move image is not moved until i release the slider (i.e. stop dragging). Is the transform blocking draw calls somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This is still a mystery for me. I have however a workaround. Performing the transform on view layer instead of the view seems to solve the problem

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    self.scaleImage.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale([sender value], [sender value], 1.0);

    CGRect targetFrame = self.moveImage.frame;
    targetFrame.origin = CGPointMake(targetFrame.origin.x + (100 * [sender value]) - 50, targetFrame.origin.y);
    self.moveImage.frame = targetFrame;
}
```

If anyone would care to explain this to me i would be very grateful. Otherwise i will try to continue with my life anyway :)